# Embedded Login Auth0 - with same-origin auth domain - whats the problem?

Tags: auth0

I have been using Universal Login with Auth0. I would like to personalise the login experience for my users, so I'm considering switching to an embedded login form and using the SDK to authenticate with my auth0 server.

I only have one application, and potentially a native mobile app in future.

Reading the docs on [Cross-Origin authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/cross-origin-authentication) it seems to suggest that the main issues here are:

- Security risks with sending credentials cross-origin and open up the risk of a phising attack
- Some browsers disable 3rd party cookies by default

And it would seem that both of these issues are solved by simply hosting my Auth0 server on the same domain as my embedded login form:

e.g `auth.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com/login`

But still the Auth0 docs strongly advise using their Universal Login, almost every piece of documentation urges it.

#### My question

Are there any further issues with an embedded login form that sends credentials to an auth0 server on the same domain? When im only developing one application, I have no need for a shared login form.

Are auth0 just encouraging the use of Universal Login for business reasons?

Comment: It's been over a month, have you found a solution? I am interested in this myself.

Comment: @JakeBellacera I have not found a concrete answer to this yet, however we have decided to opt for embedded log-in. From my initial investigation I see no attack vectors with a same domain auth server. It seems universal login is just more convenient for the common denominator as its essentially a "low-code" auth solution.